# newline \n is not working while using print statement in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code which is not working:

```
[In] f = open('f.txt')
[In] print(f.read())
hello world\nthis is a newline test\nthis is last line
```

The newline character also gets printed to the output, why?

thanks!!

Comment: Maybe you have escaped the new line in your file.

Comment: can you provide an example? i don't think i escaped them. it is as it is printed by the print statement

Comment: f.read() will read in bytes, so newlines aren't escaped. Try using f.readlines instead.

Comment: with readlines() , i get ,hello world\\nthis is a newline test\\nthis is last line

Comment: Your source file doesn't have newlines, it has literal `\n`s. So Python doesn't print newlines, it prints literal `\n`s.